# PHP assign values within in_array

Tags: php, array

What is a more efficient way of writing this sample code? Its purpose is to create a variable for days of the week based on a numerical value. This data is obtained from user input checkboxes. If the user doesn't select any options, they will be assigned the Online value. Fiddle here - https://3v4l.org/Sghnh#v7.4.30

```
    <?php
$classDays = [1,3,5];

if($classDays[0] == '') {
    $classDaysD = 'Online';
} else {
if (in_array(1, $classDays)) {
    $classDaysD = 'M';
}
if (in_array(2,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' T';
} 
if (in_array(3,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' W';
} 
if (in_array(4,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' Th';
} 
if (in_array(5,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' F';
} 
if (in_array(6,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' S';
} 
if (in_array(7,$classDays)) {
    $classDaysD .= ' Su';
} 
if ($classDaysD == '') {
    $classDaysD = 'M & W';
}
}

echo $classDaysD;
```

Here is the checkbox section of the form, viewable here http://jsfiddle.net/S9qrZ/1/:

Which days of the week are your classes for the syllabi you are about to create?

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Mon</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Tues</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Wed</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="4">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Thur</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="5">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Fri</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="6">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Sat</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="7">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Sun</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays[]" name="classDays[]" value="Online" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">Online (uncheck if face to face class)</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You code [generates a warning](https://3v4l.org/EdD63#v7.4.30) for a seemingly valid value of `$classDays`, perhaps you should solve this problem first? It would also be helpful if you gave a better description of what the code is used for and what it is suppose to accomplish. We can guess, but should we? Why should `$classDaysD = ''` result in `'M & W'` and `$classDaysD = ['']` in `'Online'`? That seems very arbitrary.

Comment: Also, what is meant by "_more efficient way_"? Is that in terms of memory and/or processing power, lines of code, or some other measure?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - https://3v4l.org/Sghnh#v7.4.30 is the link I posted and there isn't an error. The link you posted is missing the values for $classDays.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ - You've summed it up :) Primarily, my code seems repetitive so I would think it would be better to loop, but I'm not sure of the best way to go about that.

Comment: I agree, I made a mistake. I accidentally mixed `$classDays` and `$classDaysD`. This is due to the small difference between these names. Sorry, for that. Still, I would like to know what input and output you expect. How can this expression: `($classDaysD == '')`, ever be true? When should it be true?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No worries. In the posted example, I expect the output to be M W F. If the user doesn't select any options when selecting the checkboxes on the input form, they will be assigned the Online value.

Comment: So, can `'M & W'` never be a result? If that is the case, why is it there? What if the input is `[5,2,1]`? Or is the input array always in order? I think it would be helpful if the checkboxes HTML was a part of your question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The result could contain any number of days and the output will be in numerical order. I've added the checkbox HTML to my post. Thanks.

Comment: Here's what I've decided to use:

<?php
$days = [
  1 => 'M',
  2 => 'T',
  3 => 'W',
  4 => 'TH',
  5 => 'F',
  6 => 'S',
  7 => 'Su',
  8 => 'Online',
];
$classDays = [1,3];
if(count($classDays)=='0') {
$classDays = [8];
} 
$result = array_map(function ($a)  use($days) { return $days[$a]; }, $classDays);
echo implode(', ', $result);

Answer (score 2):

I can't get clear answers to my question in the comments, but I think I can try something. It would seem logical to define an array that contains the days of the week, like this:

```
const WEEKDAYS = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'S', 'Su'];
```

I have to use an array because you don't use 2 or 3 letters, but a mixture of 1 and 2 letter, abbreviations for the days of the week.

Now, instead of using day numbers in the checkboxes, and then translate this to alphabetical week days, I would just use alphabetical week days in the checkboxes, like this:

```
foreach (WEEKDAYS as $weekdayKey => $weekday) {
    echo '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' . PHP_EOL .
         '  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="classDays' . $weekdayKey . '" name="classDays[]" value="' . $weekday . '">' . PHP_EOL .
         '  <label class="form-check-label" for="classDays[]">' .  PHP_EOL .
         '    ' . date('l', strtotime('2022-01-0' . ($weekdayKey + 3))) . PHP_EOL . 
         '  </label>' .  PHP_EOL . 
         '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

See: https://3v4l.org/armtj#v7.4.30

Note that `date('l', strtotime('2022-01-0' . ($weekdayKey + 3)))` just gets the day of the week, in your local language, based on `$weekdayKey` from 0 to 6.

Now when I process the form, I already have, more or less, the correct data. But validating user input is always important. This processing could look something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['classDays']) {
    $classDaysD = implode(' ', array_intersect($_POST['classDays'], WEEKDAYS));
} else {
    $classDaysD = 'Online';
}
```

The usage of [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is there to make sure that only values from `WEEKDAYS` are accepted.

I would strongly advice you to choose another name for the `$classDaysD` variable. Something like `$classDays` would do, in my code.

I don't know how to incorporate the `'M & W'` result.